# О функции поиска совпадений

Tags: python, функции, циклы

```
a = 'dgfdjgkhdfjkghdfkgjhdfkgjhdfg'
b = 'ghj'

def f(b, y):
    b = list(b)
    i = 0
    for each in b:
        if each in y:
            i += 1
    return i
```

Если вызвать такую функцию над списком А, то насчитается 3, что очевидно неверно. А почему? Казалось бы, всё логически точно: для каждого члена списка В, если этот член в списке А, подвинуть считывалку.
Дополнительно: а как-то же ведь можно посчитать количество совпадений для каждого члена списка В?

Comment: Не надо назвать переменные матом, это неуважительно к окружающим

Comment: И приведите точный код вызова функции. Думаю у вас путаница между внешней переменной `b` и параметром функции `b`. И не только в этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто проверяете наличие символа в строке. Чтобы посчитать количество используйте метод `count`

```
def f(b, y):
    b= list(b)
    i=0
    for each in b:
        i += y.count(each)
    return i
```

Comment: спасибо большое, да, каунт посчитал. А ведь наверное, можно и для каждого члена списка посчитать, чтобы узнвть, сколько каждый член одного списка встречается в другом списке?